# MacOS won't allow me to install DjvuLibre

Tags: mac, security

I am trying to install DjvuLibre/ DjvuView which is used to ope djvu files on my MacBook. The program is downloaded as a dmg file. However, when I try to install the program by copying the program to my application folder, I get a message that MacOS can not verify that the program is free of malware. I would have to go to security and privacy settings to enable the app. However, I have to do this each time I am trying to view a djvu file. What is the solution to this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Go to /Applications in Finder.  Right-click Djvu application(s) and choose Open. Then it should allow it to run and remember you allowed it to run. It might open and close. Then double-click the App and it should open without the warning.

The error means this software was not submitted to Apple to be notarized. All 3rd party Mac Apps not distributed by the App Store need to be notarized with Apple by the developers.  They should also be signed with an Apple Developer account.

**You should only override this if you trust the App or performed your own malware analysis. Beware pirating software as malicious payloads are very common.**

Apple may remove the ability to work around this problem in the future.

Comment: Thanks. I am only downloading programs that I am confident are safe. I'm just using the MacBook for my research in the sciences. I am pretty sure that most of the programs I will need won't be available in apple store (e.g. programs that can compute the properties of some material). I'm looking for a way to automate this; automatically allow Mac to run applications downloaded from anywhere (mostly the programs are on source forge)

Comment: The way to automate those is add them to a package manager like  macports or homebrew. You can write your own portfiles/formulae At least for Macports you don't need to get trhem to the central servers but it will help others if you do. Also if the programs are on sourcforge be careful as they will be old